# Could I install ubuntu in Virtual Box using wubi?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

I am installing virtual box on windows and want to install ubuntu on this box using wubi? Or simply when I run the wubi installer, can I indicate that install on virtual box?

The problem is that I don't have nero on my machine so I can't burn the ubuntu iso file on dvd or cd(I am using windows 7).

Comment: (I've edited your question to make more sense, can you ask the other part about measuring boot as a separate question?)

Comment: @dato Windows 7 should have a built-in ISO burning utility.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use wubi: VirtualBox can install an OS direct from a .iso file, no CD required.

Just create a blank VM, and the first time you boot it VirtualBox will ask you where your install disk is. Just give it to .iso file, and you're done! :)

I'm not sure what the second part of your question means, but yes, you can run all normal programs, as long as your machine is powerful enough.

Comment: In fact, it's not possible to install Wubi in VirtualBox unless you've first installed Windows in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply select the iso file as image for a "virtual cd drive" in virtual box and boot the virtual machine from this virtual CD. Just setup a new virtual machine with an empty hard drive, select the cd image on the devices menu and boot the machine.